Getting 403 when invoking external API from within AWS Lambda (NOT VPC)
We have a lambda that is NOT associated with a VPC but does have an associated API Gateway (but no api-key required). When I internally try to invoke an external API from within my Java lambda handler (actually it invokes a static method on another service) I get a 403 response, but using the same url/headers/body in curl or Postman I get a 200. In fact I can't force the 3rd party api to return a 403 via curl/Postman, only a 400 (if the payload is bad, etc). So I know there's something going on with the lambda, but why is this happening? I shouldn't need to do anything special to allow internet access for my non-VPC lambda should I?

yes, you don't have to do anything special if your lambda is running in the default VPC with a default internet gateway.
Are you sure that there is no error in your code and everything on your VPC side is configured properly?
